# Transactions and multiple updates on the same row

Tags: mysql, transactions

How big is the performance hit of doing a single updates in a single row and multiple updates within a single transaction on MySQL?

I'm asking this because AFAIK the database spend most of it's time committing the transaction rather than "just updating" the row itself. Is this correct?

Just to clarify, I have a bunch of routines that alters a row and saves it, sometimes I call some of them sequentially, but they all flush the result to the database before calling the next one(i.e.: update the row).
What is the best approach in this case? Use a transaction or just tell them to not save and then just do a single update in the end?

Comment: Using/avoiding transactions should never be a subject of performance optimisations. Do you need transactions from your business logic point of view?

Comment: Not really. What I really want to is a way to conciliate a small and beautiful code with good performance.

Comment: So if you don't need transactions - then you don't need transactions. (sorry for being so obvious)

Comment: If no one already said I'll say it here: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Transactions are only needed if there is a chance of anything going wrong between two or more queries that modify the data, avoiding an inconsistent state. 

The best way of knowing if something is faster than other is profinling. Do some tests and share the results, please.